# Woocommerce 3.4 Shop Page disable Links

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a way to either remove the link in the thumbnail and title at Woocommerce 3.4 on the shop page or redirect to another page
(External product).
I have already tried the following code but unfortunately it does not seem to work with the current version anymore.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not just use the External/Affiliate Product type from the drop down menu in the product data section?

Comment: The product itself is created as an external product. But on the shop page, in the title and in the thumbnail is directed to the single product page. I do not want that, but would like to have either the links on the shop page removed or link to the external product.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want Affiliate product not to open in your product page. They will appear in shop/archive page only.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_external_products' );
function redirect_external_products() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) && ! empty( $post ) && ( $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() ) ) && $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $product->get_product_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

this code will redirect the user to the Affiliate link form shop page.